# How to break time(factor type - HH:MM:SS) in hour, time, seconds column? IN R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a dataset with a column time(HH:MM:SS-ZZ). The time is of class factor. I want to create new column for hour, min, sec(class:numeric) in the dataset. How can i do that ..any thoughts?

Comment: Did this help you? In any case you should select an answer so we can close the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use strsplit function:

```
strsplit("23:52:23-09", "[:-]")
```

A complete example:

```
a<-data.frame(Date=c("04:52:00-09", "03:22:23-09", 
                     "23:00:23-09", "15:12:23-09"), Dummy=1:4)
b<-data.frame(strsplit(as.character(a$Date), "[:-]"))
colnames(b)<-c("HH", "MM", "SS", "ZZ")
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a factor datetime variable to demonstrate:

```
test <- as.factor(Sys.time())
```

Load the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
```

Extract the different parts:

```
hour(test)
minute(test)
second(test)
```

Comment: Have you tried your suggestion on the format given by OP, as.factor(HH:MM:SS-ZZ)? E.g. hour(as.factor("23:52:23-09")).